# How to add two items in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a such task now and I need your help. Here is my problem:

```
lst = [
    {'price': 0.0, 'name': 'Arber Hair & Body Wash', 'prod_id': '17337', 'quantity': 2.0},
    {'price': 14.0, 'name': 'Arber Hair & Body Wash', 'prod_id': '17337', 'quantity': 1.0},
    {'price': 19.0, 'name': 'Vitamin E Illuminating Moisture Cream', 'prod_id': '21381', 'quantity': 2.0}
]
```

I need to have such result:

```
lst = [
    {'price': 0.0, 'name': 'Arber Hair & Body Wash', 'prod_id': '17337', 'quantity': 3.0},
    {'price': 19.0, 'name': 'Vitamin E Illuminating Moisture Cream', 'prod_id': '21381', 'quantity': 2.0}
]
```

It means that I need to search dictionaried in list with the same `prod_id` value and summarize their `quantity` values.
I've tried to search unique `prod_id`s and save them in a set.

```
unique = set()
for i in lst:
    if i['prod_id'] not in unique:
        unique.add(i['prod_id'])
```

But looks like it won't work because it's all are doing in a loop.
I didn't find anything similar here on stackoverflow and my head is exhausted of ideas.

Please help me to solve this puzzle. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [ask]

Comment: How is the price chosen? In your result it is `0.0` even though both have different prices initially

Comment: How do you summarize the other values? For example, why does `'price'` end up as `'0.0'` instead of `'14.0'`, or some kind of weighted average, or anything else?

Comment: Anyway, if you can't figure out how to get started: What if, instead of a list, you have a dictionary, mapping each `prod_id` to a summary dict (or to a list of separate dicts)? How could you build such a dict from your list?

Comment: with same product id which one will you choose, more price ??

Comment: about price: this value is optional and unnecessary. I need only quantity because price for 1 item I already have

Comment: @abarnert the problem is that I have only such input data. It's a list of orders. Someone bought one cream and then bought 2 more creams. I need to summarize it's orders and group them by product ID

Comment: @yakudza_m: Again: How could you build such a dict from the list you have? If you can solve that, you can solve your whole problem. If you can't solve that, you're probably not going to be able to understand any solution anyone gives you.

Comment: @abarnert actually I don't know how to build such dict from list. If I've had a couple of dicts, I could be able to solve it by myself. But I don't. Can you give me advice how to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a middle solution in this issue, thanks to @joran-beasley:

```
d = {}
for l in lst:
    _id = l['prod_id']
    if _id in d:
        d[_id]['quantity'] += l['quantity']
    else:
        d[_id] = l
```

As result we will get a dictionary of dictionaries

```
{'17337': {'price': 14.0, 'name': 'Arber Hair & Body Wash', 'quantity': 3},
 '21381': {'price': 19.0, 'name': 'Vitamin E Illuminating Moisture Cream', 'quantity': 2}}
```

Thanks to all who gave me advices!

Answer (score 1):

its not really a puzzle

```
d= {}
for item in lst.values():
   d[item["prod_id"]] = d.get(item["prod_id"],0) + item["quantity"]
```

maybe ... assuming I understand what you want ...

Comment: Thank you for showing me this solution. I've posted my result below

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [
    {'price': 0.0, 'name': 'Arber Hair & Body Wash', 'prod_id': '17337', 'quantity': 2.0},
    {'price': 14.0, 'name': 'Arber Hair & Body Wash', 'prod_id': '17337', 'quantity': 1.0},
    {'price': 19.0, 'name': 'Vitamin E Illuminating Moisture Cream', 'prod_id': '21381', 'quantity': 2.0}
]


d = {}
for l in lst:
    _id = l['prod_id']
    q = d.get(_id)['quantity'] + l['quantity'] if _id in d else l['quantity']
    l.update({'quantity': q})
    d.setdefault(_id, {}).update(l)

print d.values()
```

Answer (score -1):

To get you started, a list comprehension:

```
prod_ids =  [ entry[ 'prod_id' ] for entry in lst ]
```

is probably the first step. But to get the *unique* `prod_ids` you'll probably want to convert it into a `set`:

```
prod_ids =  set( [ entry[ 'prod_id' ] for entry in lst ] )
```

Then you can iterate over the resulting `prod_ids` and summarize the `lst` entries that match each one, using whatever rules you like to combine the entries.  For example:

```
result = []
for prod_id in prod_ids:
    matches = [ item for item in lst if item[ 'prod_id' ] == prod_id ]
    # Now combine the items in matches, which all have the same prod_id, using
    # whatever rules are necessary, until you have just one summarized item.
    # Append that to result.
```

Instead of making `prod_ids` a `set` and `result` a `list`, you could combine them into one `dict` whose keys are the product ids (Joran's answer is an example of this).

Comment: It was intended to get the OP started rather than spoon-feed, so it may require some thought. I realize that's something for which not all commenters have time.

Comment: But this doesn't get him started, because it's not useful toward any reasonable solution. Not to mention that he already has equivalent code in the original question, where it clearly hasn't helped him.

Comment: OK, I have added an example, just in case the OP wants to pursue an *un*reasonable solution.